# Adding MPVolumeview programmatically in app

Tags: iphone, airplay, mpvolumeview

Trying to add MPVolumeView programmtically in app by using the following code

```
 MPVolumeView *_volumeView = [ [MPVolumeView alloc] init];
[_volumeView setShowsVolumeSlider:YES];
[_volumeView setShowsRouteButton:YES];
[_volumeView sizeToFit];
[view addSubview:_volumeView];
```

but getting so many Semantic issue that use of undeclared identifier MPVolumeView and Invalid operands to binary expression

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPVolumeView *volumeView;
```

Getting message in red for the above statement that unknown type MPVolumeView and plus property with retain or strong must be of object type.

```
 @synthesize volumeView = _volumeView;
```

Is this the right way to add MPVolumeView programmatically in app.

Thanks for help.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011045-CH6-DontLinkElementID_3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MPVolumeView is part of the MediaPlayer framework. Did you include this in your application and did you `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>` in your .m or .h file?

Also, if you declared a property, you should create a new local variable _volumeView. Replace the first line with this:

```
_volumeView = [ [MPVolumeView alloc] init];
```

Comment: Make sure you also have `#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know how but i totally forgot to add #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>. So lots of thanks. it worked.