# How to trigger iOS volume view when press physical volume key

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm working on iOS app which can play video. It's using avplayer but it doesn't show volume indicator view when user press physical volume key like below image. I think it's system indicator view. How could I force app to show this? Thanks for you help
[image: volume indicator view]

Comment: Try this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444376/hide-device-volume-hud-view-while-adjusitng-volume-with-mpvolumeview-slider

Comment: I want to show the hud view and now I already add MPVolumeView and set showsRouteButton to yes and showsVolumeSlider to no.

Comment: That above link would do the exact opposite of what you want. To make it fit I would call sizeToFit as this link does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236636/adding-mpvolumeview-programmatically-in-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer [Hide device Volume HUD view while adjusitng volume with MPVolumeView slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444376/hide-device-volume-hud-view-while-adjusitng-volume-with-mpvolumeview-slider) is correct. I have one MPVolumeview in player view and size is zero. Remove it or give it a appropriate size will fix this